# How to give permission to PyCharm to access python project within the Ubuntu WSL 18.04 folder?

Tags: python, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on Windows 10, and I installed (and set as default version) python 3.6. The current project I am working on is in a folder within Ubuntu WSL, and PyCharm python interpreter is set to the Ubuntu python 3.6.

However, when I start PyCharm's python console, I get the following error:

```
Error:Console process terminated with error: /bin/bash: line 0: cd: /mnt/c/Users/liv/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalSate/rootfs/home/liv/My_Project: Permission denied
```

PyCharm is installed on Windows 10, and if I am understanding this correctly, the problem is that it does not have permission to access the folder where my project is stored (Ubuntu WSL), and hence it can't start the console.
How can I solve this?

Comment: did you resolve this?